# golang pipelining channels - works as a separate function, but doesn't work as a part of main function

Tags: go

I'm new to go, and at the moment I'm trying to understand how channel synchronisation works. I'm solving a test task that requires me to build a pipeline from channels. I wrote two similar solutions, but one of this doesn't work for an unknown reason (for me).

This doesn't work (the go-routines are started from the function directly):

https://play.golang.org/p/EHceKjZZ-G

This works (the go-routines are started from a separate function):

https://play.golang.org/p/QysTAVxbVc

I'm totally lost, I don't see the difference and can't understand why the first example doesn't work. Does any one have any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using a capture variable `fn` across `goroutine`, in which the variable will be overridden during iteration. What is seen by all `goroutines` is the latest job in the `funcs`. Change your code in `Pipe` function to the following:

```
for _, fn := range funcs {
    out = make(chan interface{})
    wg.Add(1)
    go func(f job, inx, outx chan interface{}) {
        f(inx, outx)
        close(outx)
        wg.Done()
    }(fn, in, out)

    in = out
}
```

It's one of [common mistake](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/CommonMistakes) in golang.

Comment: You are totally right! I tried to avoid it with in and out, but missed that with fn! Thank you very much, I couldn't sleep because of that! :D